# Hide featured image using CSS, Wordpress, Avada Them, Fusion Builder

Tags: css, wordpress

This is a wordpress website - https://smecollaborative.org/

Down the page there is a section pulling from the Events Calendar.  Each Event has a featured image.  You can use CSS to hide the featured image of each image, but the challenge is using the Fusion Builder element, the featured image is replaced with a 'placeholder' image off a calendar, and I can't get that thing hidden.

Here are the two snippets I've tried:

```
    .single-tribe_events .page-header-image-single {
        display: none;
    }

    .tribe-events-event-image img {
    display:none!important;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.fusion-events-shortcode .tribe-events-event-image {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2 snippets you tried are wrong because:

snippet 1. is targeting the header image on the tribe event single page.
snippet 2. is targeting an `img` tag which does not exist in this case.

You should target the parent item to also hide the clickable link to it:

```
.fusion-events-post div.fusion-events-thumbnail {
    display: none;
}
```

I added the extra `div` to the thumbnail selector to override the standard `display: block;` without having to use `!important`

Or, in case you only want to hide it if the image is missing you can do:

```
.fusion-events-post .fusion-events-thumbnail span {
    display: none;
}
```

This one will only target the placeholder in case it is present